# cc1plus: no such file or directory (gcc)

Tags: macos, gcc

#### Issue

Every time I try to compile something with gcc I get this error:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

#### What I tried

I have tried uninstalling gcc and re-installing it using brew.

#### Other Info

I am on a MBP 2015 running Mojave.

#### Edit 1

```
$ file $(which gcc)
/usr/local/bin/gcc: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64                                 
$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (Homebrew GCC 8.2.0) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

#### Edit 2

```
$ cat > /tmp/foo.c << EOFeof
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
EOFeof

gcc /tmp/foo.c -o /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
zsh: no such file or directory: /tmp/foo
```

Comment: What is the reason to use gcc and not clang?

Comment: Several reasons. GCC has features that clang does not, GCC is often first to adopt new standards and language features. GCC is what many others use and it is useful to have the same compiler as my peers. I like clang and usually use it, but sometimes it is necessary to use GCC.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer. Have you removed bcc from brew and validated the core system builds? Once you’re sure that compiler works, when you reinstall gcc - run `brew doctor` before and after the `brew install ` and watch for errors installing gcc itself.  I know you said you uninstalled, but this seems like something outside the gcc to me hence my expansive answer to try clang as well. Hopefully someone has a better answer. Maybe @Mark?

Answer (score -1):

Something is going to be messed up, but with the details given I don't even know where to guess what you have wrong. Instead. let's go the other way and try something super minimal that should show your failure immediately.

Here's a simple end to end test of `gcc` that ships from Apple should work. I'm using the version that ships with Mojave (ProductVersion:   10.14.3 BuildVersion:   18D109) according to the `sw_vers` command on macOS.

```
cat > /tmp/foo.c << EOFeof
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
EOFeof

gcc /tmp/foo.c -o /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo
```

Where I'd start is which actual GCC and version you're running:

```
Mac:~ me$ file /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
Mac:~ me$ file $(which gcc)
/usr/bin/gcc: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
Mac:~ me$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
Mac:~ me$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Then you can repeat the test in your flavor of `gcc` to suss out the differences or if you even need the bcc that’s not the clang implementation of a gcc like compiler.

What specific error or what specific differences do you have? Feel free to start a new thread or edit / refine your question and then @ me in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the response! I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: You deleted `foo` in `/tmp/foo && rm /tmp/foo` before running `file /tmp/foo`, so that's interesting.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @user3439894 In bash the "rm" runs only when `/tmp/foo` returns 0 - no error condition. You're correct that I did skip the `rm` to show that it was made successfully, so perhaps it would be better to edit. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @bmike, I'm well aware of `&&` and the reason for its usage; however, on your system I'm pretty sure `/tmp/foo` exited with `0` and I found it a bit interesting that `file /tmp/foo` didn't return `/tmp/foo: cannot open '/tmp/foo' (No such file or directory)` as I would expect it to on a a working system the way you laid out the commands. Also, to the comment you made for the edit, if your were worried about `/tmp` being left dirty why not use `/tmpfoo && rm foo foo.c` instead, after all both files would be created on a working system.

Comment: @user3439894 Does my edit help you reconcile the non linear ordering in the previous version of this post? See my edit comment about clarity being more important than cleanup. I thing were in agreement on just about everything.

Comment: @bmike any ideas about why my GCC installation isn't working?

Comment: Xcode does not install gcc. The gcc here is a wrapper for clang

Comment: @Mark Except it's not.  You note in the banner it identifies itself as from Homebrew.

Comment: @MarcWilson yes it is homebrew in the question but is pure apple in the answer